# jquery checkbox val() always return on

Tags: jquery

Hi after a lot of search I got a method to check my checkbox. But I dont know what is the problem. Its val() always return **on**. This is happening when I check it and also when I uncheck it. I suppose it should return **null** when unchecked. Help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ch').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
 });
```

and the html

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="ch"/> Check it out...
```

Answer (score 9):

You have set of option to check if your `checkbox` is checked or unchecked,

```
alert($(this).is(":checked")); ////return true if checked
```

Or

```
alert(this.checked); //return true if checked
```

Or

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ch" checked/>
alert($(#ch).attr( "checked")); //return checked if checked
```

Or

```
alert($(this).prop( "checked")); //return true if checked
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is whether it is checked or not for that you can check checked status

```
alert(this.checked); // or $(this).is(':checked')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/92yCK/)

Comment: Working but why its not working with alert($(this).ckecked).. Both are same..?

Comment: No. $(this)[0].checked would be the same as this.checked. this.checked is not jQuery

Comment: @Shameer the property `checked` belongs to the dom element, `$(this)` returns a jQuery wrapper element not the dom element so it does not have the `checked` property

Answer (score 2):

you could do:

```
alert($(this).prop('checked'));
```

or if you want to get the value of checkbox, then you need to add `value` attribute, like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="your_value" id="ch"/> Check it out...
```

and js

```
$('#ch').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val()); //gives you 'your_value' in any case
});
```

`$(this)` is a jQuery collection using which you can use jQuery methods to get relevant data, if you want to use `.checked`, you can do either of following:

```
this.checked
//or
$(this)[0].checked
```

that would mean:

```
$(this)[0] == this
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DP5Zn/)

Comment: Why this not working with alert($(this).attr('checked')); What is the difference between attr and prop

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ch').change(function(){
        alert($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/teXQw/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your form object a value attribute for `.Val()` to return something you can work with:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="some_usefull_value" id="ch"/>
```